# MergeSort segmentation fault in C with million values

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

MergeSort algorithm segmentation fault error when a record of one million elements is inserted, up to 300k values sort without problem.
Data Structures are given as input and based on the attempts i've tried to make, i think it's not a memory problem

```
void merge_sort(void *a, int left, int mid, int right, int size) {
    int n1 = mid - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - mid;

    char left_array[n1 * size];
    char right_array[n2 * size];  

    char *arr = (char *)a;

   



}

void merge(void* a, int left, int elem, int size) {
    if(left < elem){
        int mid = left + (elem - left)/2;
        merge(a, left, elem, size);
        merge(a, mid + 1, elem, size);
        merge_sort(a, left, mid, elem-1, size);
    }

}
```

I allocated as much memory as possible but it doesn't seem to be a memory issue

Comment: Are you allocating this big array on the stack?

Comment: Local variables, including arrays, are usually placed on the stack. The stack is a limited resource, on Windows it defaults to only one single MiB. If your variables needs more space than is possible, you will have *undefined behavior*, and very likely crashes.

Comment: OT: In C all `void *` pointers are implicitly convertible to any other data pointer. So the cast in `char *arr = (char *)base;` is not needed.

Comment: I created a function that, once the input values have been taken, if it reaches a capacity, reallocs twice as much

Comment: Look at these `char left_array[len1 * size]; char right_array[len2 * size];` which can break the stack. This is almost certainly the reason for failure with a large input.

Comment: How can I define the two temporary arrays? left_array and right_array?

Comment: With `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: You need to allocate them somewhere else in memory.

Comment: Or figure out an algorithm where you don't need to use temporary arrays that you copy back and forth. Like using the data already in-place in the input array?

Comment: And for future questions, please try to create a [mre] to show us. Something which doesn't contain unrelated problems that could distract from the actual problem.

Comment: NB: `nitems` is a misleading name: it has little to do with a number of items (except in the initial call). Better would be `right`. Also `merge` and `merge_sort` have names that are switched; that is confusing. Also: `merge_sort` has an unclosed opening parenthesis.

Comment: Now it works correctly defining with malloc and free the left_array and right_array arrays, thanks for all the help

Comment: You can shorten your unnecessarily long comparison test using `if (compar(left_array + i * size, right_array + j * size) <= 0)`.

Comment: Or check out [strategies to reduce memory in merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#In-place_merge_sort), [block merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort).

Comment: There seems to be code missing from revision 3 of your question; it was there in [rev 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76027471/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick explanation

```
char left_array[len1 * size];
char right_array[len2 * size];
```

On these lines you are allocating about four million bytes (approx. 4Gb) of memory. This memory is allocated on the stack, and the thing about stack is that it can't grow indefinately, and it has an upper bound. The default stack size on windows is 1Mb, and on linux it's 2Mb.

The reason for the crash - accessing memory outside of the stack bounds. So if you want to fix the issue, you probably would want to either allocate this memory not on the stack, allocate less memory, or make the stack larger. Since this is obviously a testing code I would assume that making the stack larger is an acceptable solution, though in this case the amounts of memory you're allocating are so large, that allocating them on heap is probably better.

You can allocate memory on the heap using the `malloc` function, you can look up the usage online. This is the simplest, and probably the best solution.

Comment: "Making the stack larger" isn't really an acceptable solution. It isn't the place to store large size of data.

Comment: On most desktop or server Linux systems, the default stack size is 8 MiB.